# Can't pull text from content control cell in Word

Tags: java, docx4j

I'm able to parse a Word document with a table/rows/cells and get text from the cells, unless the cell has content control (drop down menu). If content control is present, it won't pull anything. I've tested it trying to get anything with Text.class or Tc.class and it's not seeing either even though it's part of its XML block.

I've looked through the types of classes in docx4j.wml and tried several which I think might fit. CTSdtCell is finding the block of code I need but not doing much with it.

From the output, it's finding the sdt content but not the cells (w:tc) within it. If it can't find the cells, it won't find the text (w:t)

The document has nine rows. I removed all of the content control from the first two rows and left the other seven in tact. When it reaches a row with content control, it doesn't consider it a cell (w:tc), it's just content control (w:sdt) with no cells in it.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart;
import org.docx4j.wml.CTSdtCell;
import org.docx4j.wml.Tc;
import org.docx4j.wml.Tr;

public class ReadWordDocTest implements Utilities {

    private static final String OUTLOOK_DOC_PATH = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\workspace\\Test\\Projects\\";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        new ReadWordDocTest();

    }

    public ReadWordDocTest() throws Exception {

        String documentFilename = ("ATL.docx");

        WordprocessingMLPackage mlp = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File(OUTLOOK_DOC_PATH + documentFilename));
        MainDocumentPart mdp = mlp.getMainDocumentPart();

        List<Object> rowsList = getAllElementFromObject(mdp, Tr.class);

        rowsList.subList(0,  2).clear();    // Header stuff. Skip.

        // Rows
        for (Object row : rowsList) {

            List<Object> cellsList = getAllElementFromObject(row, Tc.class);
            List<Object> sdtObjList = getAllElementFromObject(row, CTSdtCell.class);        

            System.out.println("Cells " + cellsList.size() + " Content control " + sdtObjList.size());

        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Cells 7 Content control 0
Cells 7 Content control 0
Cells 3 Content control 4
Cells 3 Content control 4
Cells 3 Content control 4
Cells 3 Content control 4
Cells 3 Content control 4
Cells 3 Content control 4
Cells 3 Content control 4
```

The XML sample from a cell using content control

```
<w:sdt xmlns:dsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2008/diagram" xmlns:cppr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/coverPageProps" xmlns:odx="http://opendope.org/xpaths" xmlns:c14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2007/8/2/chart" xmlns:xdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing" xmlns:odgm="http://opendope.org/SmartArt/DataHierarchy" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:dgm="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/diagram" xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" xmlns:we="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/webextensions/webextension/2010/11" xmlns:pvml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:powerpoint" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:sl="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/schemaLibrary/2006/main" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:comp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/compatibility" xmlns:b="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography" xmlns:c="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" xmlns:xvml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:oda="http://opendope.org/answers" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:odc="http://opendope.org/conditions" xmlns:cdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chartDrawing" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:odi="http://opendope.org/components" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:lc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/lockedCanvas" xmlns:odq="http://opendope.org/questions" xmlns:wetp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/webextensions/taskpanes/2010/11" xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid">
<w:sdtPr>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:sz w:val="18"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="18"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:id w:val="1239367024"/>
    <w:placeholder>
        <w:docPart w:val="059F92C89F2F410BB7231E2BAA981321"/>
    </w:placeholder>
    <w:date>
        <w:dateFormat w:val="M/d/yyyy"/>
        <w:lid w:val="en-US"/>
        <w:storeMappedDataAs w:val="dateTime"/>
        <w:calendar w:val="gregorian"/>
    </w:date>
</w:sdtPr>
<w:sdtContent>
    <w:tc>
        <w:tcPr>
            <w:tcW w:w="1170" w:type="dxa"/>
        </w:tcPr>
        <w:p w:rsidRPr="007D4D1F" w:rsidR="00040B4E" w:rsidP="00040B4E" w:rsidRDefault="00040B4E">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:ind w:left="0" w:firstLine="0"/>
                <w:jc w:val="center"/>
                <w:cnfStyle w:val="000000000000"/>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:sz w:val="18"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val="18"/>
                </w:rPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:sz w:val="18"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val="18"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>02/01/2019</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
    </w:tc>
</w:sdtContent>
```

Method from my interface

```
default List<Object> getAllElementFromObject(Object obj, Class<?> toSearch) {

    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();

    if (obj instanceof JAXBElement)

        obj = ((JAXBElement<?>) obj).getValue();

    if (obj.getClass().equals(toSearch)) {

        result.add(obj);

    } else if (obj instanceof ContentAccessor) {

        List<?> children = ((ContentAccessor) obj).getContent();

        for (Object child : children) {

            result.addAll(getAllElementFromObject(child, toSearch));
        }

    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: A content control wrapped around a cell is https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/wml/CTSdtCell.java but it may be wrapped in a JAXBElement.  What does getStringListFromObject say?  And what is your ultimate objective - there may be a better way :-)

Comment: Objective is to just pull the string that shows in the doc. I don't care about anything in the drop down list. I just need that string value. When I remove content control from the same document, I'm able to get my program to behave the way I need.

getStringListFromObject returns nothing since size() is 0. When I try to print out the results in a String array, it shows "[ ]"

Comment: Add the code in the getStringListFromObject method to your question please

Comment: Lost that method in a rewrite. I made a new class testing the same thing. Added the get object method from that. Updated my questions to reflect changes. Basically, when it encounters sdt tag, it stops looking for anything else. Using docx4j-6.0.1

Comment: CTSdtCell does not implement ContentAccessor, so you need logic to handle that.  Something like if instanceof SdtElement then getSdtContent, which does implement ContentAccessor:  https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/wml/SdtContent.java

Comment: Perfect! I'll add your solution as the answer. I never would have found that. Thanks a lot!  I figured it was a 'horse of a different color' issue, so what's the reason for CTSdtCell not implementing ContentAccessor like Tbl, Tr, Tc?

Answer (score 0):

Per JasonPlutext's response, CTSdtCell does not implement ContentAccessor. Route it through SdtElement and use its getSdtContent() method.

```
default List<Object> getAllElementFromObject(Object obj, Class<?> toSearch) {

    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();

    if (obj instanceof JAXBElement) {

        obj = ((JAXBElement<?>) obj).getValue();

    }

    if (obj.getClass().equals(toSearch)) {

        result.add(obj);

    } else if (obj instanceof ContentAccessor) {

        List<?> children = ((ContentAccessor) obj).getContent();

        for (Object child : children) {

            result.addAll(getAllElementFromObject(child, toSearch));

        }

        // CTSdtCell does not implement ContentAccessor. SdtElement does.
    } else if (obj instanceof SdtElement) {

        List<?> children = getAllElementFromObject(((SdtElement) obj).getSdtContent(), toSearch);

        for (Object child : children) {

            result.addAll(getAllElementFromObject(child, toSearch));

        }
    }

    return result;
}
```